# Plot overlayed distributions of non uniform data

Tags: r

is there a way to plot (value by year colouring dots by Hospital and avoiding overlapping distributions) on the same graph a data frame that looks like this?

> ```
>  Department     Hospital      Value      Year
>      A            HS1          0.3       2015           
>      B            HS1          0.9       2015
>      C            HS1          0.4       2015
>      D            HS1          0.2       2015
>      A            HS2          0.1       2015
>      G            HS2          0.3       2015
>      B            HS2          0.4       2015
>      F            HS2          0.9       2015
>      A            HS1          0.2       2016           
>      B            HS1          0.6       2016
>      C            HS1          0.8       2016
>      D            HS1          0.1       2016
>      A            HS2          0.4       2016
>      G            HS2          0.1       2016
>      B            HS2          0.6       2016
>      F            HS2          0.3       2016
>      H            HS2          0.1       2016
>      M            HS2          0.2       2016
> ```

My point is that, for some years like 2016 there are departments not only absent in the same hospital for the year before like the case of HS2 but also that there are departments present in one hospital like HS2 not present for example in HS1.

These data are a subset of a long data frame.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I have used `geom_point` with transparency factor `alpha = 0.5`. In order to avoid overlapping, `geom_jitter` might be better.

```r
df1 <- " Department     Hospital      Value      Year
     A            HS1          0.3       2015           
     B            HS1          0.9       2015
     C            HS1          0.4       2015
     D            HS1          0.2       2015
     A            HS2          0.1       2015
     G            HS2          0.3       2015
     B            HS2          0.4       2015
     F            HS2          0.9       2015
     A            HS1          0.2       2016           
     B            HS1          0.6       2016
     C            HS1          0.8       2016
     D            HS1          0.1       2016
     A            HS2          0.4       2016
     G            HS2          0.1       2016
     B            HS2          0.6       2016
     F            HS2          0.3       2016
     H            HS2          0.1       2016
     M            HS2          0.2       2016"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2

ggplot(df1, aes(factor(Year), Value, color = Hospital)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  xlab("Hospital") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

With `geom_jitter` the horizontal random spread of the points can be controlled with the `position` argument.

```r
set.seed(2022)  # make the results reproducible

ggplot(df1, aes(factor(Year), Value, color = Hospital)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), alpha = 0.5) +
  xlab("Hospital") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to avoid points to be on the same line because I really have many data points? Just move (by hospital) a little bit to the left/right